# What triggers the onProgressChanged method of the OnSeekBarChangeListener interface in android?

Tags: android

This should be a pretty simple question, what triggers the onProgressChanged() method when programming in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgressBar (from android.widget package) has method `doRefreshProgress()` which calls 'onProgressChanged()' the following way:

```
if (callBackToApp && id == R.id.progress) {
    onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser);
}
```

`doRefreshProgress()` in turn get called then any change or set max for Progress / 
Secondary Progress or attached to window. Check out the source - [ProgressBar](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java;h=f3f18d585dbdd5e7d69cdc44ce46ae470187d10a;hb=HEAD) and [SeekBar](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/SeekBar.java;h=2737f9414c46fff0abd0fb2599002876206553a8;hb=HEAD).